# PDO prepare/execute SQL issue

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I've an issue regarding PDO's prepared statements.

In the code below, example 1 uses prepared statements. However, this code does not produce the desired results. Example 2 produces the desired results but does not use prepared statements.

Example 1 uses `?` placeholders in the SQL string, string values are then bound to these placeholders later and then executed (as you would expect).

**Code below:**

```
<?php

// debugging
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

// db vars
$host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'cakeTut'; 
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'password'; 

// try to connect to db, else catch exception.
try{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

///////////////////////////////////////
// Example 1
///////////////////////////////////////

// query vars
$tablename = 'users';
$id = 'id';
$first_name = 'first_name';
$last_name = 'last_name';

// query string w/placeholders, then prepare query
$sql = "SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM $tablename";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

// binding query vars to placeholders in query string
$query->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(2, $first_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(3, $last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

// execute query & print out query details for debugging
$query->execute();
$query->debugDumpParams();

// fetch result set & print it
$resultSet = $query->fetchAll();    
print_r($resultSet);

// loop through result set and print cols.
foreach($resultSet as $row) {
    echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];
    echo "<br>";
}

///////////////////////////////////////
// Example 2
///////////////////////////////////////

// create query string with out placeholders, prepare and execute
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name` FROM `users`";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

// get result set & print it
$resultSet = $query->fetchAll();
print_r($resultSet);

// loop through result set and print cols.
foreach($resultSet as $row) {
    echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Here's the output of the code:

**Example 1's** `$query->debugDumpParams();`

```
SQL: [25] SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM users Params: 3 Key: Position #0: paramno=0 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #1: paramno=1 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Position #2: paramno=2 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2
```

**Example 1's** `print_r($resultSet);`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => id [0] => id [first_name] => first_name [1] => first_name [last_name] => last_name [2] => last_name ) [1] => Array ( [id] => id [0] => id [first_name] => first_name [1] => first_name [last_name] => last_name [2] => last_name ) [2] => Array ( [id] => id [0] => id [first_name] => first_name [1] => first_name [last_name] => last_name [2] => last_name ) [3] => Array ( [id] => id [0] => id [first_name] => first_name [1] => first_name [last_name] => last_name [2] => last_name ) [4] => Array ( [id] => id [0] => id [first_name] => first_name [1] => first_name [last_name] => last_name [2] => last_name ) )
```

**Looping through Example 1's result set and print cols.:**

```
id first_name last_name
id first_name last_name
id first_name last_name
id first_name last_name
id first_name last_name
```

**Example 2's** `print_r($resultSet);`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [0] => 3 [first_name] => fiona [1] => fiona [last_name] => mac [2] => mac ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [0] => 4 [first_name] => ronan [1] => ronan [last_name] => duddy [2] => duddy ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 5 [0] => 5 [first_name] => tom [1] => tom [last_name] => thumb [2] => thumb ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 30 [0] => 30 [first_name] => ronan [1] => ronan [last_name] => mcl [2] => mcl ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 31 [0] => 31 [first_name] => Admin [1] => Admin [last_name] => admin [2] => admin ) )
```

**Looping through Example 2's result set and print cols.:**

```
3 fiona mac
4 ronan duddy
5 tom thumb
30 ronan mcl
31 Admin admin
```

Am I missing something? Shouldn't both examples in the code above print out the same data i.e. example 2? I've googled about and example 1's code matches basic examples on prepared statements.

Many thanks, 
Rónán

Comment: You can't do this => `SELECT ?, ?, ?`

Comment: Where did you read that you can define column names or table names as parameters?

Comment: To put it another way - you use bound parameters for values, not for column or table names.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't know what to select "ahead" of time, because it's unknown; being "questionable" `?`. It's kind of like putting the wagon before the horse, as it were. When you ask a question `?`, it's because you don't know the answer yet, right? ;-) Well, there you go; same thing applies here. Set a variable for it instead `$column1="column";` then `SELECT $column1...`, if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: I see now. Good analogy Fred! Many thanks everyone! :) A link to the documentation explains it similarly: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#111977

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepared statement placeholders can only represent VALUES in the query. You cannot use them for table names, field names, or any other SQL keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (somefield = ?) // ok
SELECT ? FROM foo WHERE (somefield = 2) // bad - cannot use for field name
SELECT * FROM ? WHERE   (somefield = 2) // bad cannot use for table name
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (somefield = 2) ORDER BY somefield ? // again bad, can't use for sort order
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (? = 2) // again bad, can't use for field name
```

Comment: For the last example is it possible to do:
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ($somefield = 2)";`

Thanks

Comment: @ronanduddy: that's not a placeholder. that's PHP variable interpolation, and opens the query up to injection attacks. It is **NOT** something you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, you cannot use parameters for table/column names in PDO.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Please note this:

Won't work:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM ?  WHERE calories < ?');
```

THIS WORKS!

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit WHERE calories < ?');
```